# How to show Extra free only not add in order total in order summary

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have code for add extra fee in order in magento 2, now my requirement is the extra fee can only show will be not add in order total

[image]

the extra free can also add in order total but I can not add that

I need order total 155 not 160

my code is that

```
public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    )
    {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        if (!count($shippingAssignment->getItems())) {
            return $this;
        }

        $enabled = $this->helperData->isModuleEnabled();
        $minimumOrderAmount = $this->helperData->getMinimumOrderAmount();
        $subtotal = $total->getTotalAmount('subtotal');
        if ($enabled && $minimumOrderAmount <= $subtotal) {
            $fee = $quote->getFee();
            $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $subtotal);
            $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $subtotal);
            $total->setFee($fee);
            $quote->setFee($fee);
            $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal());
            $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: can you please share the code for an extra fee. I have a requirement to add extra fee into order totals and summary as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you add following updated code ?

```
  public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


    $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
    $fee = 100; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
    $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

    $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

    $total->setFee($balance);
    $total->setBaseFee($balance);

    $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal());
    $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal());


    return $this;
} 

protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total)
{
    $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
    $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
    $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
}
```

Comment: hello i have add new question can you please review that and please help me

Answer (score 1):

you can change following function in your code like this

```
public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
            if (!count($shippingAssignment->getItems())) {
                return $this;
            }

            $enabled = $this->helperData->isModuleEnabled();
            $minimumOrderAmount = $this->helperData->getMinimumOrderAmount();
            $subtotal = $total->getTotalAmount('subtotal');
            if ($enabled && $minimumOrderAmount <= $subtotal) {
                $fee = $quote->getFee();
                $total->setFee($fee);
                $quote->setFee($fee);
            }
            return $this;
}
```

Comment: in witch file can you guide me

Comment: app\code\Webkul\Test\Model\Total\Customfee.php

Comment: $enabled = $this->helperData->isModuleEnabled();
        $minimumOrderAmount = $this->helperData->getMinimumOrderAmount();
        $subtotal = $total->getTotalAmount('subtotal');
        if ($enabled && $minimumOrderAmount <= $subtotal) {
            $fee = $quote->getFee();
            $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $subtotal);
            $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $subtotal);
            $total->setFee($fee);
            $quote->setFee($fee);
            $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal());
            $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal

Comment: see my code and guide me

Comment: comment is not readable properly can u add in your question ?

Comment: yes i also added in my quation

Comment: added in quation please guide me

Comment: check I have I edited my answer

Comment: okay let me i check

Comment: that now work for me thank you

Comment: hello can you please help i wan to set calulation of text as per sub total i do code alredy but not reflected please see my new quation

Comment: Please check my new answer.